# Loopback - Set ACL on Object level

Tags: javascript, acl, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have successfully added "Class"-level ACL's, to only allow authorized users access my model:

```
.../server/ModelObj.js

"acls": [
  {
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
    "permission": "DENY"
  }
]
```

This is great, but my applications needs ACL's on a even lower level - object level.

When a User, which belongs to a Role, creates a new object, the object must only be accessible by other users, who have the same role.

Is this the way to go around the problem in Loopback, or do they provide a different way?

Thanks in advance, 
Jesper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to implement this using a custom [role resolver](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles#Definingandusingroles-Dynamicroles). The idea is to create a role and a custom resolver and determine a user's access to the given model at runtime. Here's a partial example (note that you would need to create the role, and members, etc as well).

```
// perhaps in a boot script?
app.models.Role.registerResolver('teamMember', function(role, context, cb) {
  if (context.modelName === 'ModelObj') {
    context.model.findById(context.modelId, function(err, instance) {
      if (err) { /* handle it... */ return cb(err); }
      // check the instance for something to determine access
      // execute callback with switch for access (or not)
      cb(null, true);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion - I actually implemented my own fix that way. It works, but I do think its a very manual process to achieve something rather common for most applications. Appreciate the confirmation in my problem and solution, from you though :)

Comment: Do you have any easy solution to provide this functionality application wide? Right now this works if you request a specific object in the db, but if you request for all objects, this will be not set. Not forget, update and so forth.

Comment: I suppose you could use the `access` operation hook for that.

Answer (score 0):

This week I started a [loopback mixin](https://github.com/Hooptaplabs/loopback-object-acls) to support acls on object-level. We needed dynamic acls on a instance-level that may change over time. We saw your question and made a search to find some plugin/mixin/middleware that someone could be made to support this, but we didn't found nothing.

If you are still interested on this I will be very happy to have your feedback, as I want to make this mixin to work anywhere and not only on our product.

My plan is to have a first version this week. Since monday I made a simple, synchronous acl library on object-level. Later I added support as loopback-mixin and support for resolvers that could obtain data to make a decission. I want to add support for make a layer of 'sugar', where a simple property can make acls. So if you have a model with property "stock", nobody can call method 'buy' if stock is less than 1.

Thanks!

Comment: yes I would gladly like to discuss your approach! We have are currently running a custom developed solution in production now, and the results are promising. How can I contact you?

Comment: Hi again, my team has open source our solution to solve this problem: https://github.com/jesperbruunhansen/loopback-object-acl. Any feedback or help is appreciated!